# Querying the size, cache-line sizes, and associativities of caches in Intel CPUs

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, cpuid

With AMD processors, there are CPUID 0x8000005u and 0x8000006u to gather the sizes, associativites and cache-line-sizes of the different cache-levels.

For Intel CPUs, there is only application note 485 with a table of different cache-sizes which can be gathered from lower cpuid-levels. But this document hasn't been updated for years.

So is there a convenient way to get this data from Intel CPUs?

Comment: Looks to be covered in [the manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf). CPUID leaves (`eax`) 2 and 4 give you cache information that can be parsed out. The formulae and tables are there in the manual. I believe this information is kept up to date. Have you actually tried doing this and gotten incorrect results? Or did you get stuck somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks, it's CPUID-level 0x4 described on page 214 (pdf-page 316).

Comment: Does anyone know since which CPU this type of cache-descriptors are supported?

Comment: At least from Pentium 4 (the leaf 2). Probably even before that according to [this](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel0000673_P3_Katmai_CPUID.txt). IDK about the leaf 4.

Comment: According to [the table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D0:_Highest_Function_Parameter), you can assume that Pentium Pro and later support leaf 2. You'll need a Pentium 4 with HyperThreading or later for leaf 4. Of course, you shouldn't hardcode this. Do what the manuals and Wikipedia advise: call CPUID first with leaf 0 and see what the highest supported leaf is. Then, if it's greater or equal to 2, call CPUID to obtain the leaf 2 information. If it's greater or equal to 4, call CPUID to obtain the leaf 4 information. Otherwise, it's not supported.

Comment: According to the documentation on page 3-191, there are fields for the associativity, the type of cache and whatever. But I don't see any fields for the size of the cache; am I eyeless?

Comment: I think you have to calculate the size from the information given. Don't remember for sure, though. Been a long time since I exercised the CPUID instruction to its fullest potential.